# Sum of sum of a function

Tags: summation

I want to evaluate $\sum^{30-b}_{a=2}\sum^{28-c}_{b=2}\sum^{26-d}_{c=2}\sum^{24}_{d=2}1$. But the command

`Sum[Sum[Sum[Sum[1, {d, 2, 24}], {c, 2, 26 - d}], {b, 2, 28 - c}], {a, 2, 30 - b}]`

only gives `23 (29 - b) (27 - c) (25 - d)`

How can I write a code to generate the correct output?

Comment: The sequence of your sums is wrong. Change the order for it to make sense. E.g. the outermost sum goes from a=2 to 30-b but b is already summed over in the sum next to it so it has no value.

Comment: My  intention is to get the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$ where$x_i\geq 2$. How should I construct the correct summation?

Comment: Maybe someone else can look at doing it your way, but you can do `IntegerPartitions[30, {4}] // Select[#, AllTrue[#, # >= 2 &] &] &` and look what the functions do in the documentation. Basically you ask mathematica for all sums of 4 integers summing to 30 and filter out those where all the summands are greater than 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum itself should be

```
Sum[1, {d, 2, 24}, {c, 2, 26 - d}, {b, 2, 28 - c}, {a, 2, 30 - b}]
```

> 86802

although I don't know what does it have to do with your comment: "get the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$ where $x_i\geq 2$". For this purpose, use

```
IntegerPartitions[30, {4}, Range[2, 30]] // Length
```

> 136

If you want to treat, e.g., `{24, 2, 2, 2}` as a different solution than `{2, 24, 2, 2}`:

```
Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[30, {4}, Range[2, 30]] // 
  Flatten[#, 1] & // Length
```

> 2300

Answer (score 2):

This is close to what you appear to be trying to do:

```
Count[Flatten[
  Table[Total[{a, b, c, d}],
         {d, 2, 24}, {c, 2, 26 - d}, {b, 2, 28 - c}, {a, 2, 30 - b}]], 30]
```

> 2300

( @corey979's approach is undoubtedly way faster )

Answer (score 2):

The OP seems to be asking 2 different questions:

For the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$ with $ x_i\geq 2 $

```
SeriesCoefficient[Series[((x^2 - x^31)/(1 - x))^4, {x, 0, 31}], 30]

(* 2300 *)
```

Hi george;

You are of course familiar with the concept of a generating function as a tool to solve many combinatorics problems. And many combinatorics problems come down to Diophantine equations just like this one:

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$

The number of solutions to the above equation can be represented as the multiplication of 4 polynomials.

$g(x)=\left(\frac{x^2-x^{31}}{1-x}\right)^4= (x^2 + x^3 +x^4 + x^5 + ... x^{30})^4$

Where the rational function on the LHS is called the generating function of the term on the RHS.

```
Expand[(Table[x^k, {k, 2, 30}] // Total)^4]
```

If you check the coefficient of x^30 you will see 2300 which is the answer we seek.

All of this can be done better by using the series and series coefficient commands.

```
SeriesCoefficient[Series[((x^2 - x^31)/(1 - x))^4, {x, 0, 31}], 30]
```

The above commands are very fast because Mma is very good at multiplying polynomials and getting series for us. The book "Applied Combinatorics" Alan S. Tucker, Chapter 6 is all that is necessary.

Comment: this maybe needs some explanation.

Comment: @george2079 Will do, right away!